# Proving $\ln x$ is differentiable using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My math instructor is asking me to prove differentiability using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of differentiability. I tried doing it for $\ln x$ at $x=1,$ but I'm stuck somewhere.

I can't seem to proceed from this point:
$|\ln x/(x-1) - 1|<\epsilon.$ I tried using the fact that $\ln x<x,$ but I can't seem to proceed. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Taylor series for ln ? If so, do. If you defined ln as the reciprocal of the exponential, make the change of variables $x=e^u$ and look at the limit $u \to 0$.

Comment: What definition do you have for $\ln x?$

Comment: The Taylor series of $\ln x$ pretty clearly depends on knowing $\ln x$ is differentiable, @SuspiciousFred

Comment: Well, I thought it might be used as definition of ln.

Comment: We need to know the definition of $\ln x$ you are using.

Comment: @SuspiciousFred I think you want "inverse," not reciprocal.